# Why doesn't Numbers remember my last cell position?

Tags: ipad, numbers

For latest release of Numbers for iPad, it seems that it doesn't remember the active cell when I close the spreadsheet.

I have spreadsheets with many (several hundred) rows and in previous releases, when I close and then re-open the sheet, it would remember what cell I had been in and display at that point again.

Now, every time I close and re-open the sheet, it displays a cell somewhere near the top of the sheet and I then have to swipe loads of times to get back to the bottom where I want to add a new row.

Has anyone else noticed this behavior and do you have a solution?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this was a known issue.

The latest version released today (2015-11-11) Version 2.6.1 has this note:

> - Resolves and issue where spreadsheets would not open back to their last saved positions.

See if updating to this latest version solves your issue.

[image: Release notes Numbers 2.6.1]